# Cron is running, but order confirmation messages aren't being sent

Tags: php, email, magento, curl, cron

Is there a bug in the Magento Core code?
I did not alter any of Magento core code, but I'm getting this error. If there is a bug, what is the fix?

I'm using Scheduler, Magento 1.9.

Cron is set up and working... however my order confirmation emails are stuck in core_email_queue.

I'm getting this message:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home3/ourdail7/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php on line 240
```

This is my cron command:

```
wget -O /dev/null -q https://ourdailybreaddesigns.com/cron.php> /dev/null
```

I've also tried

curl -s -o /dev/null http://www.ourdailybreaddesigns.com/cron.php. /dev/null

I don't know why my order confirmation emails aren't being sent. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your code has an error, not your cron task

Comment: Can you explain please?